# Get div height from directive $watch function while div is rendering

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to Angular and I am trying to write an error_div directive for user registration where the error_div shows up with listed errors if the username/password is not valid.

Here is my directive:

```
    angular.module(APP_NAME).directive('errorDiv', function($timeout) { 
       return {
          template: '<li data-ng-repeat="error in login_errors">' +
                        '{{error}}' +
                    '</li>',

          link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
              scope.$watch('login_errors', function() {
                  console.log(document.getElementById('error_div_login').offsetHeight);
              }, true);
          }
       };
    });
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="error_div_login" error-div></div>
```

The problem is if there are three errors which generates three list elements that increases the div height to 56px, the

```
console.log(document.getElementById('error_div_login').offsetHeight);
```

will only return 42 which is the height of the first two list elements.

To get 56, I need to put  the console.log in a $timeout ,like

```
$timeout(function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('error_div_login').offsetHeight);
}, 100);
```

My guess is that the console.log get executed while Angular is rendering the div, but are there any more proper way to get around?

In fact, my purpose is just to get the div height when the div content changes and then do some GUI staff.

Comment: Can you provide any more details on just what you want to do with the div height? There may be better, native CSS solutions/recommendations depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi @Mike, my registration box div is just fit in size with username and password and I need to resize the registration box if error_div appears

Comment: You should be able to get away with doing that with only HTML and CSS. Here's an example "Sign-In" box with validation errors. If you edit the HTML to remove the error list div, you'll see the login box just resizes itself, and if you add it back, again the box resizes. You'll most likely just need to take the absolute height you defined in your CSS off. Use margins and padding around your inner elements to achieve desired offsets and visual space. http://cdpn.io/Cqrlk

Comment: @MikeP , it doesn't http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ctpfB

Comment: Ugh, I sent the wrong link. My bad. Anyway, @Bertrand, you need to remove the absolute height defined on that box. Hopefully this works - you should see a blue background, and the errors are contained in the div. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xHArv

Comment: Now it does, excellent. By the way, nice design in that pen :)

Comment: @MikeP, Thank you man! Nice design :P

Comment: That pen isn't mine, I found it linked off the code pen home page and I forked it to make a few mods to demonstrate my point. The orig pen can be found at the first link I posted